# How to start docker with nominatim

Tags: docker, nominatim

I started docker with this command:

```
docker run -it --shm-size=4g \
  -e PBF_URL=https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us-latest.osm.pbf \
  -e REPLICATION_URL=https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us-updates/ \
  -e IMPORT_US_POSTCODES=true \
  -e IMPORT_TIGER_ADDRESSES=true \
  -e IMPORT_WIKIPEDIA=/nominatim/extras/wikimedia-importance.sql.gz \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v /osm-maps/extras:/nominatim/extras \
  --name nominatim \
  mediagis/nominatim:4.0
```

It takes quite some time to load the data..  When I do `docker images` I see this:

```
REPOSITORY           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
mediagis/nominatim   4.0       3097bc96440b   3 weeks ago   875MB
```

For some reason I woke up this morning and the box I had this running on was off..   I really hope I don't have to reload all the data again..  Is there a way to start this back up without reloading data?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the log file of the Docker container..

```
docker logs -f <CONTAINER ID>
```

..and you will probably see that it is still loading or that it has run out of disk space.

The OSM file for the US https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us-latest.osm.pbf is huge. You are trying to build a database for the USA as a whole which will take days to complete. This should probably be done in the cloud on a machine with higher performance than your local machine or on a cluster of machines.

Try use a smaller country first which will build and start quickly, like the [Maldives](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/maldives.html) for instance

```
http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/maldives-latest.osm.pbf
```

If this works, then I would suggest to try a state like [Kansas](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/kansas.html). Even this one will take several hours to start

```
http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/kansas-latest.osm.pbf
```

The mediagis Docker container offers special options to keep the data if the Docker container is deleted and recreated, but they have to be specified already when you create the container:
https://github.com/mediagis/nominatim-docker/tree/master/4.3#persistent-container-data

The official recommendation is also to use flatnode storage for bigger imports such as Europe or North America
https://github.com/mediagis/nominatim-docker/tree/master/4.3#flatnode-files